# Почему интуитивно кажется, что слово борсетка пишется через А?

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Какие фонетические закономерности срабатывают? Я думаю, что должны быть в этом смысле похожие слова, которые пишутся через А и встречаются даже чаще, чем «борсетка». Что это за похожие слова и в чём их похожесть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из словаря Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру (ред. 2014 года)

**БАРСЕТКА; БОРСЕТКА**,  ж. [итал. borsetta - сумочка] Небольшая сумка для предметов, необходимых деловому человеку в течение рабочего дня.

**Пример:** Одет сугубо по-граждански: фирменные джинсы, такая же шведка, дорогая кожаная **барсетка**. [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но… (2011)]

**Так борсетка или барсетка?**

**А. Мнение из Интернета:**

1) Нельзя игнорировать сложившуюся практику употребления. Борсетка зафиксирована в орфографическом словаре Лопатина, но написание **бАрсетка втречается по данным Яндекса в 12 раз чаще**, чем написание борсетка.

2) **Происходит** от франц. boursette, bourse – кошелек. Есть мнение, что этимология иная: "борсетка" происходит от итальянского borsetta – дамская сумочка – а не от французского boursette, иначе пришлось бы говорить "бурсетка". По-моему, версия итальянского происхождения выглядит более правдоподобно.

3) **У нас это слово появилось в 90-е годы**, когда в магазинах стала появляться импортная, в том числе итальянская, кожгалантерея. Возможно, продавцы так и писали на ценниках - "борсетта", а покупатели (в основном, новые русские) превратили это слово в "борсетка".
Но поскольку для русского языка характерна так называемая редукция гласных (изменение звучания в безударной позиции), то произносим и слышим мы "барсетка". Не зная происхождения этого слова, многие и писать его начали через А. Это можно увидеть не только в Интернете, но даже и в печатных изданиях.

**Б. Как правильнее?**

Итак, понятно, почему существуют **два варианта написания.** У каждого слова своя судьба: ожидаемая запись способом транслитерации (по буквам) однозначно не сложилась в трудные 90-е годы, и что теперь делать? **Надо узнать происхождение корня:** слово греческое, латинское? И поискать в языке этимологических родственников. Оказывается, родственники есть, это слово "бурса" - название общежития духовных семинарий (в русском языке с 1803 года).

**Происхождение греческое:** из польск. bursa (с XVI в.) или нем. Burse, которые восходят к ср.-лат. bursa, греч. βύρσΒ̄ "мешок", с переносным значением "товарищество". Сначала кожа, шкура, мех для вина, потом мешок, сумка, далее касса общежития и само общежитие. Тогда скорее бурса - бурсетка/ борсетка, но не барсетка.

В. **Почему же нам хочется писать "барсетка",** ведь в нашем языке много слов с корневой безударной буквой О, произносимой как А, например "корсет". (Корсет  - от франц. corset, от corps — тело, способ транслитерации действует исправно). Может быть, дело в фонетике слова? В двусложных словах буква О пишется легче, и итальянскую сумку можно было бы назвать "борса" (а уж потом борсетка), отличая ее хотя бы от барса, а вот просто  "барсетку" с малопонятным происхождением, которую ни с чем не спутаешь, можно записать согласно произношению, что и было сделано в 90-е годы.